# C# IndexOutOfRangeException unexplained

Tags: c#, indexoutofrangeexception

I'm getting a weird Index out of Range Exception.

Here is my code snippet:

```
string[] st2 = **An Array of up to 10**;

// If not enough in st2, add from st
if (st2.Length < 10)
{
    string[] st = **An Array of up to 10**;
    try
    {
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = st2.Length - 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            st2[i] = st[index];
            index = index + 1;
        }%%%
    }
    catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
    {

    }
}
```

I placed the try and catch to see if I could simply ignore the exception, however that is not working.

The exception is thrown at the %%%. Any ideas? I've gone in debug just to ensure that it is not either of the arrays, and in both cases, i and index have both been acceptable. (throws at index = 1 even though st is confirmed 10 in length)

Comment: Did you try to clean the solution and restart visual studio?`

Comment: Why not `for (int i = 0; i < st2.Length; i++)`?   Your logic doesn't make any sense.

Comment: The loop will access `st2[st2.length]` on its aexond iteration, which is beyond the end. You can't enlarge .net arrays by assigning to unused indices.

Comment: According to you question, you can have arrays of *different lengths*, but you treat them as they are of the *same length*. What exactly you´re trying to do?

Comment: `Array.Copy(st2, st, st2.Length); ` will solve this for you

Comment: Why not `st2.Concat(st).ToArray()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array is giving this exception. Because its size is smaller than 10. You need to copy `st2` and `st` to new array with size 10. an later assign it to `st2`

```
string[] st2 = **An Array of up to 10**;

// If not enough in st2, add from st
if (st2.Length < 10)
{
    string[] st = **An Array of up to 10**;
    try
     {
        string[] st3 = new string[10];
        Array.Copy(st2, st3, st2.Length); 
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = st2.Length; i < 10; i++)
        {
            st3[i] = st[index];
            index = index + 1;
        }
        st2 = st3;
     }
     catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
     {

     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Variable st has only 1 item, see following line : st3[i] = st[index];.  I goes from 0 to 9 and the exception occurs when i = 1.

Comment: Hiya there, while this may well answer the question, please be aware that other users might not be as knowledgeable as you. Why don't you add a little explanation as to why this is actually a problem? Thanks!